# How to find out MIBs supported on HP-UX system?

Tags: snmp, hp-ux

I have the following system, and when I did a snmpwalk, I got an error message that prevents me from "walking" the entire tree.

Is there a way to find out the MIBs supported by the SNMP Agent? (like SysORTable)

Name/OID: sysDescr.0; Value (OctetString): HP-UX ed B.11.11 U 9000/800 1187474676
Name/OID: sysObjectID.0; Value (OID): hp9000s800

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to get the documentation for the system and see what MIBs are supported.